# div overriding placement within html table

Tags: html, css

I have a table element on a page here with the first row configured with a colspan=2 and a div inside the row like this below.  For some reason the search element is forcing itself to the top of the page and completely outside of the table.  I can't seem to track down why this is occuring instead of displaying within the table like it should.

Sample URL: http://tinyurl.com/9rjd2ta

```
    <table width="100%" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
    <div>my content</div>
    </td>
    </tr>
<tr><td>other content
```

Comment: The search component is not inside the td with colspan. Do view-source in your browser to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your code might be like this

```
<tr colspan="2">
<td >
<div>my content</div>
</td>

<td>other content</td>
```